# How many times a date has occured in a Date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to find how many times two days (1, 15) has occurred in a date range in Excel.

Let's say the date range is
1/4/2022 - 17/6/2022

so, the no. of times 1 and 15 has occurred 6 times.

I tried to look for inbuilt functions, couldn't find any so tried to do it via programming style (I am in programming field) but it has too many if and else and converting it to excel structure is getting troublesome.

I can share cpp program code if necessary if it helps in excel, which I don't think would be.

Is there any better way to do in excel?

Comment: What about countif() ?

Comment: I saw countif function but it uses cells to count occurance  but mine only has two field, one is start end and one is end date. Is there any other way to use this function?
I will drop a image: https://imgur.com/a/iHIxILU

Comment: So what about thinking about the maths like working out the months between the start date and end date. Then you can work out how many 1's there are and how many 15's there are based on the start etc. As a programmer this should not be a problem.

Comment: I have actually done it in programming, but converting that programming code into excel is getting troublesome.

Comment: @Pankaj-Talesara So what do you need here the counts of 1 and 15's only ? and what is your excel version we are going to work on here? will it be always 1 and 15?

Comment: yes, always 1 and 15. also what you mean by excel version? mine is office 365 if that's you mean

Comment: Edited previous reply, it's officie 365 or sheets.google.com, can use any of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula as shown below in **Excel**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=SUM(--(TEXT(SEQUENCE(B1-A1+1,,A1),"d")+0={1,15}))
```

---

In **Google Sheets**, the below formula works for me as well,

[image]

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(--(TEXT(SEQUENCE(B1-A1+1,1,A1),"d")+0={1,15})))
```

Comment: It works in excel, but give this error in sheets.google.com "Function SEQUENCE parameter 2 value is 0. It should be greater than or equal to 1.". Can I make it work in both?

Also thank you very much

Comment: @Pankaj-Talesara Yes I have posted both. please refer i have edited.